# Move google maps marker when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I spent a lot of time to solve this, and can't figure it how to work, so here is my base:

```
<script>
 function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng("43.2697,26.9165"),
          zoom: 8  };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
        var marker=new google.maps.LatLng("43.2697,26.9165");
        var main=new google.maps.Marker({position:marker});
        main.setMap(map); 
      }  


        function moveMarker(lat,lng) {
           var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng)); 
        //???????
            }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Now - in HTML i have a button and two text fields. When button is clicked, it fire moveMarker function and pass new latitude and longitude - entered in fields. The goal is that marker must move to new position, and map must be centered - accordingly. I've tryed a lot of hints, but - cant access marker object(with name Main in my case) in order to move it to new position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your marker ("main") is local to your initialize file.  To access it from an HTML click event, it needs to be in the global scope.

```
<script>
var main = null;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng("43.2697,26.9165"),
          zoom: 8  };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
    var marker=new google.maps.LatLng("43.2697,26.9165");
    main=new google.maps.Marker({position:marker});
    main.setMap(map); 
}  


function moveMarker(lat,lng) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng)); 
  main.setPosition(latlng);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but after trying your suggestion, error appear:TypeError: main is null

Comment: sorry - typo above. I mean: error message appear: <<TypeError: main is null>>

Comment: Sorry, typo in my answer (I missed removing the "var" in front of main, your naming confused me).

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. It works, and naming here is really confusing, but it's linked to another context. So, thank you very much :)